# How to use oracle thin driver?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, driver

I want to use type 4 driver . I'm using eclipse, oracle 10g . i downlaoded ojdbc14.jar and placed that in the javaBuildPath.

Here is my code. it is showing me error

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

    public class Demo
    {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:8080:";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"system","1234");
            String sql ="select sysdate as current_day from dual";
            PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();
            while(result.next())
            {
                System.out.println("Date" + result.getString("current_day"));
            }      
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please read this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Although there are many smart people on SO, I doubt any of them are mind readers. How about showing us the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the thin client this way:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
         ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@999.999.999.999:8888:INSTANCE_NAME", 
          "user", "password");

conn.close();
```

Comment: For instance name what should i give?

Comment: @KKaran The name of the Oracle instance. I think that's missing from your code. Ask the DBA for it.

Comment: Ya i added "XE" but still the same problem. it is shoing me Database name missing a component

Comment: @KKaran Use the IP address instead of "localhost". Check the port number. Check the instance name.